# AttributeError: 'main' object has no attribute 'update_question_number'

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

```
#imports
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as ms
import sqlite3

# make database and users (if not exists already) table at programme start up
with sqlite3.connect('logins.db') as db:
    c = db.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (username TEXT NOT NULL ,password TEX NOT NULL);')
db.commit()
db.close()

#main Class
class main:
    def __init__(self,master):
        # Window 
        self.master = master
        # Some Usefull variables
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()
        self.n_username = StringVar()
        self.n_password = StringVar()        
        #Create Widgets
        self.widgets()

    #Login Function
    def login(self):
        with sqlite3.connect('logins.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()

        #Find user If there is any take proper action
        find_user = ('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? and password = ?')
        c.execute(find_user,[(self.username.get()),(self.password.get())])
        result = c.fetchall()
        if result:
            self.logf.pack_forget()
            self.new()    
        else:
            ms.showerror('Oops!','Username Not Found.')

    def new_user(self):
        #Establish Connection
        with sqlite3.connect('logins.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()

        #Find Existing username if any take proper action
        find_user = ('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?')
        c.execute(find_user,[(self.username.get())])        
        if c.fetchall():
            ms.showerror('Error!','Username Taken Try a Diffrent One.')
        else:
            ms.showinfo('Success!','Account Created!')
            self.log()

        #Create New Account 
        insert = 'INSERT INTO user(username,password) VALUES(?,?)'
        c.execute(insert,[(self.n_username.get()),(self.n_password.get())])
        db.commit()

        #Frame Packing Methods
    def log(self):
        self.username.set('')
        self.password.set('')
        self.crf.pack_forget()
        self.head['text'] = 'LOGIN'
        self.logf.pack()

    def cr(self):
        self.n_username.set('')
        self.n_password.set('')
        self.logf.pack_forget()
        self.head['text'] = 'Create Account'
        self.crf.pack()

    def new(self):
        self.logf.pack_forget()
        self.crf.pack_forget()
        self.head['text'] = 'Welcome Back'
        self.newf.pack()

    def quiz(self):
        self.newf.pack_forget()
        self.head['text'] = 'Welcome to the psychology revision quiz'
        self.quizf.pack()

        self.Qn = 1
        self.quizScore = 0
        self.correctAnswer = ''  # <-- create it at start (and use better name)

        self.update_question_number() # <-- get question number
        self.update_question()        # <-- get new question

        def update_question_number(self):
        # Get question's number

            query = "SELECT MAX(qnumber) FROM questions"
            cursor.execute(query)
            row = cursor.fetchone()

            self.recordNum['text'] = row[0]

        def update_question(self):
        # Get new question

            query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE qnumber=?"
            cursor.execute(query, (self.Qn,))
            row = cursor.fetchone()

            self.question['text'] = row[0]

            self.answer1['text'] = row[1]
            self.answer2['text'] = row[2]
            self.answer3['text'] = row[3]
            self.answer4['text'] = row[4]

            self.correctAnswer = row[5]    

        def confirmAnswer(self):

            if self.enterAnswer == self.correctAnswer:
                self.rightOrWrong['text'] = "Correct"
                self.quizScore += 1
            else:
                self.rightOrWrong['text'] = "Incorrect"

            if self.Qn < self.recNum:
                self.Qn += 1           # <-- get new question
                self.update_question() # <-- get new question

            else:
                self.rightOrWrong['text'] = "Quiz Complete! Your score was: {}".format(self.quizScore)

    #Draw Widgets
    def widgets(self):
        self.head = Label(self.master,text = 'LOGIN',font = ('',35),pady = 10)
        self.head.pack()
        self.logf = Frame(self.master,padx =10,pady = 10)
        Label(self.logf,text = 'Username: ',font = ('',20),pady=5,padx=5).grid(sticky = W)
        Entry(self.logf,textvariable = self.username,bd = 5,font = ('',15)).grid(row=0,column=1)
        Label(self.logf,text = 'Password: ',font = ('',20),pady=5,padx=5).grid(sticky = W)
        Entry(self.logf,textvariable = self.password,bd = 5,font = ('',15),show = '*').grid(row=1,column=1)
        Button(self.logf,text = ' Login ',bd = 3 ,font = ('',15),padx=5,pady=5,command=self.login).grid()
        Button(self.logf,text = ' Create Account ',bd = 3 ,font = ('',15),padx=5,pady=5,command=self.cr).grid(row=2,column=1)
        self.logf.pack()

        self.crf = Frame(self.master,padx =10,pady = 10)
        Label(self.crf,text = 'Username: ',font = ('',20),pady=5,padx=5).grid(sticky = W)
        Entry(self.crf,textvariable = self.n_username,bd = 5,font = ('',15)).grid(row=0,column=1)
        Label(self.crf,text = 'Password: ',font = ('',20),pady=5,padx=5).grid(sticky = W)
        Entry(self.crf,textvariable = self.n_password,bd = 5,font = ('',15),show = '*').grid(row=1,column=1)
        Button(self.crf,text = 'Create Account',bd = 3 ,font = ('',15),padx=5,pady=5,command=self.new_user).grid()
        Button(self.crf,text = 'Go to Login',bd = 3 ,font = ('',15),padx=5,pady=5,command=self.log).grid(row=2,column=1)

        self.newf = Frame(self.master,padx =12,pady = 12)
        Button(self.newf,text = 'Start New Quiz',bd = 3 ,font = ('',15),padx=5,pady=5,command=self.quiz).grid()
        Button(self.newf,text = 'Progress',bd = 3 ,font = ('',15),padx=5,pady=5).grid()

        self.quizf = Frame(self.master,padx =10,pady = 10)

        # v-- create empty labels
        self.recordNum = Label(quizf, text='')
        self.recordNum.pack()

        self.question = Label(self.quizf, text='')
        self.question.pack()

        self.answer1 = Label(self.quizf, text='')
        self.answer1.pack()

        self.answer2 = Label(self.quizf, text='')
        self.answer2.pack()

        self.answer3 = Label(self.quizf, text='')
        self.answer3.pack()

        self.answer4 = Label(self.quizf, text='')
        self.answer4.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Create Object
    #and setup window
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Login Form')
    root.geometry('400x350+300+300')
    main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I am creating a tkinter/SQlite code which uses a interative GUI for a "psychology revision quiz". I am a amateur when it comes to tkinter within python.

But anyway, this is the the error I get:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1533, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "S:\year 13\computing project\project\MAIN PROJECT CODE.py", line 91, in quiz
    self.update_question_number() # <-- get question number
AttributeError: 'main' object has no attribute 'update_question_number'

This error will also occur for "update_question" which is just below "update_question_number".

I included the whole code so it can be tested by any of you, I'm sorry if it comes across confusing but i tried to make the structure as understandable as possible with some comments to help. I have no idea how to fix this error but I'm sure its something stupid that can be easily fixed. Thanks, guys :)

Comment: You have an indentation error. Your `update_question_number` method should be de-dented one level. Currently, it's a method inside the `quiz` method.

Comment: I've just done that but now it says cursor is not defined on those functions @ErikCederstrand

Comment: That's correct. You haven't defined `cursor`, so it wouldn't have worked before, either. You proably want to create `cursor` like it's done in your `update_question()` method.

Comment: I had defined cursor at the top of the code as 'c' so just changed it to that for it to work. Thanks for your help. @ErikCederstrand